# Adding text view to surface view

Tags: android, layout, textview, surfaceview

i use this a s surface view in my application and now i want to add text view to this programmatically. How can i do that.

```
"<com.csfcse.udrawer.UdrawerDrawingSurface
  android:layout_width="fill_parent" 
  android:layout_height="fill_parent"
  android:id="@+id/drawingSurface" 
        android:layout_gravity="left" />"
```

Thanks......

Answer (score 17, accepted):

An option may be to have a FrameLayout with two children, first the SurfaceView, then whatever you want to overlay on the SurfaceView.  In the sample below, the second View in the FrameLayout is a horozontil LinearLayout with a Button and a TextView.  The FrameLayout displays all its children as piled in Z order with the first child at the bottom and all children positioned at the upper left corner.  In this case the LinearLayout has Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL (I think you could do the same thing with padding on the LinearLayout.

I have never found much (good) documentation about how SurfaceViews (or any of the screen drawing) works.  There may be a problem with flickering or refresh, but I don't see much problem on my Froyo Evo.  (This test app draws 'twirling' lines on the SurfaceView below the Button and TextView.

[image: SurfaceView with views overlaying it]

If the question is simply: How do you programmatically add a TextView to a Layout that was created by a XML inflated Layout, then, get a reference to the Layout instance and call addView() to it.

```
Layout lay = parentLayo.findViewById(R.id.drawingSurfaceParent);
TextView tv = new TextView(this);
tv.setText("New textview");
lay.addView(tv);
```

Answer (score 7):

You'll need to use the Canvas and a corresponding text draw method:

[drawText(String text, int index, int count, float x, float y, Paint  paint)](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawText%28java.lang.String,%20int,%20int,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29).

Comment: Would it be possible to make the text editable with this approach?

Answer (score 3):

This is not possible, a SurfaceView cannot contain other Views.